# populate php return result into multiple limited size divs

Tags: php, html, css

How can i populate the result of `<?php the_content(); ?>`  equally into two DIVs.

```
left_div{width: 200px;}

right_div{width: 200px;}
```

Comment: what is the the result of the_content() ?

Comment: you may cut into two part by its length but you should take care of line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is split the contents of `the_content()` to equally fit two divs. If thats the case you would find the total characters in `the_content()`, divide it by two, and show it in each div:

```
$length = strlen(get_the_content()) / 2; // notice get_the_content();
$content1 = substr(get_the_content(), 0, $length);
$content2 = substr(get_the_content(), $length);
```

and then show it in the divs:

```
<div class="left">
    <?php echo $content1; ?>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <?php echo $content2; ?>
</div>
```

Of Course this would split it by the number of characters and not words.

Answer (score 0):

See css's floats. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp That'll suffice.
edit: nvm, misunderstood. php allows you to do the following: `$string = "Hello bro."; echo $string[0];` therefore you can `$cut = round(count($string) / 2); $left = substr($string, 0, $cut); $right = substr($string, $cut);` That should do.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that an array is returned since you haven't specified then use a foreach statement, I'm also assuming left_div, right_div are classes

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
   if ($key % 2 == 0)
   {
      echo "<div class='left_div'> $value </div>";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "<div class='right_div'> $value </div>";
   }
}
```

hope this will suffice you did give barley any information

**NVM it sounds like it returns a string and someones already answered it**

Answer (score 0):

You could do this programatically as suggested by other respondents. The problem with this is what if you content has differing font sizes i.e. <h1> etc the contents would not be visually balanced.

You could use the CSS3 column-* format which lets the browser decide on the column contents and where the text should flow.

This spec is not supported by IE 6,7,8 or 9 and you need to use vendor prefixes for every declaration. For example:

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap  : 30px;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap  : 30px;
     -o-column-count: 2;
     -o-column-gap  : 30px;   
        column-count: 2;
       column-gap  : 30px;
```

Using this method you only need a single div to hold the contents.